# In the tag component I created using AntDesign, the first value of the array comes as an empty string

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, antd

I use Ant Design and Redux Form. I can use the tag component(Select). But I have a problem. The field that should normally be empty is a string value as the first element. I want the field to come empty. Another problem is that it doesn't see the placeholder value.

[image]

> ```
> <Field
>    name="select"
>    component={FormSelect}
>  // tokenSeparators={[',']}
>    onFocus={(e: any) => e.preventDefault()}
>    onBlur={(e: any) => e.preventDefault()}
>    mode="tags"
>    label="Select"
>    rules={[
>    {
>     required: true,
>     message: 'Input something!',
>    },
>    ]}
>    >
>     
>
>    <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
>    <Option value="disabled">Disabled</Option>
>    <Option value="Yiminghe">yiminghe</Option>
>   </Field>
>
>
>
>
>   const FormSelect = (Component: any) => ({
> meta,
> input,
> hasFeedback,
> label,
> name,
> children,
> rules,
> placeholder,
> onChange,
> ...rest }: {
> input: any;
> meta: any;
> children: any;
> hasFeedback: any;
> label: any;
> name: any;
> onChange: any;
> placeholder: any;
> rules: any; }) => {
> const hasError = meta.touched && meta.invalid;
> return (
>     <Form.Item
>         name={name}
>         label={label}
>         validateStatus={hasError ? 'error' : 'success'}
>         hasFeedback={hasFeedback && hasError}
>         help={hasError && meta.error}
>         rules={rules}
>     >
>         <Component {...input} {...rest} placeholder={placeholder}>
>             {children}
>         </Component>
>     </Form.Item>
> ); };
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed problem.

> ```
>     const FormSelect = (Component: any) => ({ meta, input, hasFeedback,
>     label, name, children, rules, placeholder, onChange, ...rest }: {
>     input: any; meta: any; children: any; hasFeedback: any; label: any;
>     name: any; onChange: any; placeholder: any; rules: any; }) => { const
>     hasError = meta.touched && meta.invalid; 
>
>      if (input.value === '') {
>      input.value = [];    // the part I added
>      }
>
>     return (
>     <Form.Item
>     name={name}
>     label={label}
>     validateStatus={hasError ? 'error' : 'success'}
>     hasFeedback={hasFeedback && hasError}
>     help={hasError && meta.error}
>     rules={rules}
> >
>     <Component {...input} {...rest} placeholder={placeholder}>
>         {children}
>     </Component>
> </Form.Item> ); };
> ```